# Notation of physical quantity with applied operator

Tags: notation, units

I'm writing my Bachelor's degree at the moment. I have one equation expressing the force generated by a rotor depending on the angular velocity $\omega_m$. At the moment it is written as
$$
F_m(\omega_m) \approx \begin{cases}
                    -4.515 \cdot 10^{-5} \; |\omega_m|^{2.023} \;\mathrm{\frac{N}{rad~s^{-1}}},\quad\omega_m< 0 \\
                     1.191 \cdot 10^{-4} \; |\omega_m|^{1.972} \;\mathrm{\frac{N}{rad~s^{-1}}},\quad\omega_m\ge 0\end{cases}
$$

Now if I am not mistaken my units aren't correct, as I am raising $\mathrm{{rad~s^{-1}}}$ to the power of $2.023$/$1.972$.

Is there a notation that's specifying that I only want to raise the numerical value of $\omega_m$ but not the unit?
Like this (according to https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physikalische_Gr%C3%B6%C3%9Fe#Schreibweise)?
$$
F_m(\omega_m)=a\cdot|\{\omega_m\}|^{b}\quad N
$$

Comment: Why not divide the quantity by the unit before raising it to the fractional power?

Comment: To me it appears as though the units are not being raised to the power as they are outside the vertical bars, looks to me like the number out front probably compensates for that power.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty You mean like this? $F_m(\omega_m)=a\cdot |\frac{\omega_m}{rad~s^{-1}}|^b\quad N$

Comment: @Triatticus I thought so as well, but thinking longer about it I'm getting less sure. (Also wolframalpha says otherwise.)

Comment: What I meant to say is as written the units seem to already be outside the expression, as if the dimensional analysis was already done and that $|\omega_m|$ just stands for the numerical value of the angular speed. We would need more context on how this expression was generated.

Comment: That's the idea, yes. I was wondering if this notation is actually saying that or if it's kind of sloppy to write it that way.

Comment: @Triatticus Oh, i forgot to add (and can't yet edit my comments): I fitted $a\cdot|x|^b$ to ten data points each (for $\omega_m <0 and \omega_m \ge 0$).

With "looks to me like the number out front probably compensates for that power" Do you mean that $a$ should have the unit $$\frac{1}{(rad\;s^{-1})^{b-1}}$$? That seems a bit overcomplicated to me..

Comment: @wuppl it's the only thing that makes sense to me, that's the only way you'd get the appropriate units in the end.

Comment: Thanks! I have solved it like this:
$$
F_m(\omega_m) \approx \begin{cases}
                    -4.515 \cdot 10^{-5} \; |\frac{\omega_m}{rad/s}|^{2.023} \;\mathrm{N},\quad\omega_m< 0 \\
                     1.191 \cdot 10^{-4} \; |\frac{\omega_m}{rad/s}|^{1.972} \;\mathrm{N},\quad\omega_m\ge 0\end{cases}
$$
I think it's more readable like this way.